# SELECT DISTINCT statement in MySQL is taking 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm reasonably new to MySQL and I'm trying to select a distinct set of rows using this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sp.atcoCode, sp.name, sp.longitude, sp.latitude
FROM `transportdata`.stoppoints as sp
INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfsstop_times as st ON sp.atcoCode = st.fk_atco_code
INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfstrips as trip ON st.trip_id = trip.trip_id
INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfsroutes as route ON trip.route_id = route.route_id
INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfsagencys as agency ON route.agency_id = agency.agency_id
WHERE agency.agency_id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

However, the select statement is taking around 10 minutes, so something is clearly afoot.

One significant factor is that the table `gtfsstop_times` is huge. (~250 million records)

Indexes seem to be set up properly; all the above joins are using indexed columns.  Table sizes are, roughly:

```
gtfsagencys - 4 rows
gtfsroutes - 56,000 rows
gtfstrips - 5,500,000 rows
gtfsstop_times - 250,000,000 rows
`transportdata`.stoppoints - 400,000 rows
```

The server has 22Gb of memory, I've set the InnoDB buffer pool to 8G and I'm using MySQL 5.6.

Can anybody see a way of making this run faster?  Or indeed, at all!

Does it matter that the stoppoints table is in a different schema?

EDIT:
EXPLAIN SELECT... returns this:

[image]

Comment: How does this perform if you omit the `DISTINCT` qualifier? What do you get when you use `EXPLAIN` on the query?

Comment: What is the explain plan? Paste it into pastebin or a gist

Comment: I'm not sure how I would test that, since if I omit the qualifier then roughly 250 million rows will be returned.  Sorry if this seems like nonsense, I'm a little new to testing/debugging queries.

Comment: Try adding an index on (sp.name, sp.longitude, sp.latitude, sp.atcoCode); see [GROUP BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) in the manual for some reasons why (GROUP BY optimization advice is often applicable to [DISTINCT optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html).) But yes, let's see an EXPLAIN, too, please.

Comment: what file system is used? what raids are used? what drives are used? e.g. ssds?

Comment: @CarlosP Please post the `EXPLAIN` of your statement.

Comment: Have edited question to include the EXPLAIN.   @Sergey I'd rather not go into the file system unless it's likely to be the issue; it's nothing particularly special though; standard HDD and no RAID array.

Comment: How many does the query return? (approximately)

Comment: looking at the explain plan it returns less than 10k

Comment: It returns approx 350,000 rows

Comment: also with this amount of data the io can be a real problem even for index reading so i would assume the sharding is definitely a way to go here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to find a collection of stop points, based on certain criteria.  And, you're using `SELECT DISTINCT` to avoid duplicate stop points.  Is that right?

It looks like atcoCode is a unique key for your stoppoints table.  Is that right?

If so, try this:

```
SELECT sp.name, sp.longitude, sp.latitude, sp.atcoCode
  FROM `transportdata`.stoppoints` AS sp
  JOIN ( 
     SELECT DISTINCT st.fk_atco_code AS atcoCode
       FROM `vehicledata`.gtfsroutes AS route
       JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfstrips AS trip ON trip.route_id = route.route_id
       JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfsstop_times AS st  ON trip.trip_id = st.trip_id
       WHERE route.agency_id BETWEEN 1 AND 4
  ) ids ON sp.atcoCode = ids.atcoCode
```

This does a few things:  It eliminates a table (agency) which you don't seem to need.  It changes the search on agency_id from `IN(a,b,c)` to a range search, which may or may not help.  And finally it relocates the `DISTINCT` processing from a situation where it has to handle a whole ton of data to a subquery situation where it only has to handle the ID values.

(`JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are the same. I used `JOIN` to make the query a bit easier to read.)

This should speed you up a bit.  But, it has to be said, a quarter gigarow table is a big table.

Comment: +1 for thinking about the actual SQL and spotting those optimisations.  I didn't even know that you could use `JOIN (SELECT...)` as valid syntax. This has cut my query times in half, thank you.  Just going to check out the other proposed answer.

Comment: This is indeed a significant optimization on what I had, thanks for the great answer.

Comment: By the way, @Carlos P, leave anything you don't need out of the list of columns you `SELECT`.  Are you actually using the `name` and `atcoCode` values in your application?  If not, don't ask for them: this result set is a third of a megarow or so, and it takes time to shuffle that much data from server to client.

Comment: I do eventually use them, yes - and there are a lot more columns I'm not retrieving!

Comment: +1 Nice explanation. My query went from being unresponsive and dropping the connection to returning 1000 rows (under limit) in under 1.5s. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Having 250M records, I would shard the gtfsstop_times table on one column. Then each sharded table can be joined in a separate query that can run parallel in separate threads, you'll only need to merge the result sets.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in your answer what you mean by "sharding"? Thanks.

Comment: He means this http://xeround.com/blog/2011/11/mysql-sharding-vs-mysql-partitioning and here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would this work?  Would merging the result sets not in itself be as time-consuming as the original job, since we're looking for distinct items?

Comment: No, because the queries run on smaller tables and their result sets are smaller as well.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to reduce how many rows of **gtfsstop_times** SQL has to evaluate.  In this case SQL first evaluates  every row  in the inner join of **gtfsstop_times** and  **`transportdata`.stoppoints**, right?  How many rows does `transportdata`.stoppoints have?  Then SQL evaluates the WHERE clause, then it evaluates DISTINCT.  How does it do DISTINCT?  By looking at every single row multiple times to determine if there are other rows like it.  That would take forever, right?

However, GROUP BY quickly squishes all the matching rows together, without evaluating each one. I normally use joins to quickly reduce the number of rows the query needs to evaluate, then I look at my grouping.

In this case you want to replace DISTINCT with grouping.

Try this;

```
SELECT sp.name, sp.longitude, sp.latitude, sp.atcoCode

FROM `transportdata`.stoppoints as sp
    INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfsstop_times as st ON sp.atcoCode = st.fk_atco_code
    INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfstrips as trip ON st.trip_id = trip.trip_id
    INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfsroutes as route ON trip.route_id = route.route_id
    INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfsagencys as agency ON route.agency_id = agency.agency_id

WHERE agency.agency_id IN (1,2,3,4)

GROUP BY sp.name
    , sp.longitude
    , sp.latitude
    , sp.atcoCode
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but it actually *increased* the query time.  I tried it with a much smaller query (`WHERE agency.agency_id = 1`) that normally takes 4-5sec and it took approx 8secs.   `sp.name`, `sp.longitude`, `sp.latitude` aren't indexed, could that be the reason?   I'm not sure I understand the logic to grouping by all four of these columns; is this necessary and, if so, should I index them all?  I'm worried that the performance hit of indexing them all could outweigh the benefit.

Comment: In your opinion is this way of doing it better than @Ollie Jones answer, as his suggestion seems to perform a lot quicker.

Comment: Can I also add that I made an error in my question, the DISTINCT column is sp.atcoCode - this may explain the anomaly ?

Comment: Actually I think @Ollie Jones has the best answer. He quickly reduces the number of rows evaluated, "...it relocates the DISTINCT processing from a situation where it has to handle a whole ton of data to a subquery situation where it only has to handle the ID values" And you are correct, you only need to group the columns that should be distinct; in this case my grouping did slow it down. I have successfully used grouping, fewer columns, increased WHERE clauses, etc. to reduce run time. I was working on my answer while Ollie was posting, otherwise I would have recognized the better answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There other valuable answers to your question and mine is an addition to it.  I assume `sp.atcoCode` and `st.fk_atco_code` are indexed columns in their table.

If you can validate and make sure that agency ids in the `WHERE` clause are valid, you can eliminate joining `` `vehicledata ``.gtfsagencys` in the JOINS as you are not fetching any records from the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sp.atcoCode, sp.name, sp.longitude, sp.latitude
FROM `transportdata`.stoppoints as sp
INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfsstop_times as st ON sp.atcoCode = st.fk_atco_code
INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfstrips as trip ON st.trip_id = trip.trip_id
INNER JOIN `vehicledata`.gtfsroutes as route ON trip.route_id = route.route_id
WHERE route.agency_id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: Thanks, although I do believe @Ollie Jones already spotted this?  Appreciate the answer though.